# Binding GridView with List of Strings

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a List that I am binding to a GridView, therefore my GridView will have only one column of these string values. I want to have a proper header-text for this column. Please help me. See what I have attempted to do:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="95%">

<Columns>

<asp:BoundField HeaderText="My List" />

</Columns>

</asp:GridView>
```

And in code behind:

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();

:

:

// code to populate myList

:

:

GridView1.DataSource = myList;

GridView1.DataBind();
```

When I run this code, I get two columns in the GridView. First column having header-text as “My List” and having blank rows, whereas the second column having header-text as “Item” and having rows with myList values. I want to have only one column in my GridView having header-text as “My List” and rows with the values of the myList object.

Thanks

Comment: perhaps `GridView1.DataSource = myList.ToArray();` would do?

Comment: Hi Nishit Change Header Text after binding Gridview then it works check the code i posted.

Comment: Check this: https://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Binding-Arrays-to-GridView-in-ASP-Net-With-Code-Examples

Answer (score 3):

Or you can do it like this:

**Aspx:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="test" HeaderText="Text" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**Code:**

```
var ls=new List<string>();
ls.Add("Test");
ls.Add("Test2");
gv.DataSource=ls.Select (l =>new{test=l});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `AutoGenerateColumns="false"` to disable the second column; I'm not sure how you would bind a string array; since it outputs Item, maybe add `DataField="Item"` to your grid definition.  Or, bind to an anonymous object:

```
this.gvw.DataSource = mylist.Select(i => new { Data = i });
```

And then in your bound column, specify Data as the text field.

Option 3 is to leave the `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` (the default) and remove your column.

Comment: FYI, `Datafield="Item"` does not work.  I ended up using the linq projection which works just great.  Could not autogenerate columns because I want to apply an ItemStyle in my Column definition.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following will give you the results you are looking for:

```
        <asp:gridview id="MyGridView" runat="server" showheaderwhenempty="true" autogeneratecolumns="false" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="My List">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Column1" runat="server" Text=<%# Container.DataItem %>></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        </asp:gridview>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this programmatically in the `RowDataBound` event.

```
protected void GridView_MyList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
              ((Label)e.Row.Cells[1].Controls[0]).Text = "My List";
            }
        }
```

And your `GridView` control will be like

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView_MyList" runat="server" 
Width="800px" OnRowDataBound="GridView_MyList_RowDataBound"></asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

```
 List<string> l = new List<string>();
            l.Add("computer");
            l.Add("laptop");
            l.Add("palmtop");

            GridView1.DataSource = l;
            GridView1.DataBind();
            GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[0].Text = "My List";
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Grid `AutoGenerateColumns="false"`

Answer (score 0):

**just use Container.DataItem**

.cs

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
GridView1.DataSource = myList ;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

.aspx

```
    <asp:gridview ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="nasdc" runat="server" Text=<%# Container.DataItem %>></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
```

[http://forums.asp.net/t/1050997.aspx?How+to+bind+a+GridView+to+a+List+string+](http://forums.asp.net/t/1050997.aspx?How%20to%20bind%20a%20GridView%20to%20a%20List%20string%20)

Answer (score -1):

method 1:

make auto generate columns property true

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="95%" autogeneratecolumns = "true">

</asp:GridView>
```

method 2:

make auto generate columns property false

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" Width="95%">
    <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="My List" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: method 2 does not work - it seems you can't make `BoundField` work without a valid "DataField" value.